# PHP GET or POST multiple names of same name

Tags: php, httprequest

If several fields are POSTed or requested via GET, and two have the same name, will PHP always reliably return the latter one?

Eg having `test.php?field=foo&field=baz` and

```
echo $_REQUEST['field'];
```

may I expect the output would be 'baz' ?

Comment: PHP by default will use the LAST encountered value. But that's not written in stone and could change in future versions. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#92439

Comment: the answer to your questions is: It depends on PHP configuration. The exact description how `$_REQUEST` works is actually in the PHP manual already: http://php.net/_REQUEST - Also you can just test that, so hve you tried?

Comment: A test doesn't answer what I might expect in every situation, it only answer what might happen in one situation...

Comment: The ini setting variables_order has some influence on this, thank you for the hint. But even there is no documentation about the order of names inside one of `POST` or `GET`...  so one should maybe not rely on it?

Comment: I meant the priority of which value is used for multiple occasions of the same name, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

this will produce an array,REQUEST['field'], you will have to iterate

```
<?php
foreach ($REQUEST['field'] as &$value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

you just have to check how far this syntax is correct. But, this is the idea

Comment: You perhaps want to test so before you answer as well.

Comment: Surely this will only be the case if it's test.php?field[]=foo&field[]=baz ??

Answer (score 0):

Till now in php uses last value.

in  test.php?field=foo&field=baz it always print baz. if you echo $_GET['field']

Comment: Yes, I experience this too.. but there is no documentation on it, so it's risky to depend on it.

Comment: Ya sure you should not depend on this. It's good practice to give unique and specific name to each value you and passing in get or post.